# moment.js unable to convert utc date to local date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have the following date in utc format which I want to convert and display as local date time.

```
// utc
date = 'Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)';

// convert to local
moment.utc(date).local().format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

Expected results using the above should be:

```
Thu Oct 27 2016 08:00:00
```

But actual results are being displayed as follows i.e. the time is not changing?

```
Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00
```

Comment: Won't `' (GMT Standard Time)'` throw it off?

Comment: No, but `+0100` will.

Comment: UTC is a standard, not a format. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- Your input is a string, in a nonstandard format.  You probably got it by taking a `Date` object and calling the `.toString()` function, but that doesn't mean it's suitable for parsing by moment.  If you look in the debug console, you'll find a warning message, because you passed in something moment doesn't understand natively and so it is passing it back to the `Date` constructor.  See [the user guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/), which explains that you must pass a format specifier when you have custom input.
- Your input contains a time zone offset of `+0100`.  That means the 7:00 time is at UTC+1, which is equivalent to 6:00 UTC.  This is the value the moment has when you first parse it with `moment.utc(yourInput)`
- You then convert 6:00 UTC back to local time when you call the `local()` function.  That's the 7:00 UTC+1 you are seeing.

How to resolve this depends on what you are actually wanting to do.  You said you expected 8:00 UTC, but that doesn't make sense from the input you gave because  `7:00 (+1) == 6:00 (+0)`.

If what you meant is that you wanted to assert that the original time value was indeed UTC, and not UTC+1, even though it's in your input, then provide a format string that only contains the parts you care about.  Moment's default loose parsing mode will ignore anything extraneous.

```
date = 'Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)';
moment.utc(date, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss').local().format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

In other words, your input date is only `Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00` here, and the rest is ignored.  You are asserting that it's in UTC by passing it in to `moment.utc`, and then when you convert it to local it will end up at 8:00.

However, though that's what you asked for, my guess is that `date` is actually a JavaScript `Date` object, whose string output of `.toString()` is what you are showing here.  In that case, the `Date` object is already representing a specific point in time, which is 6:00 UTC.  So it doesn't matter whether you do `moment.utc(date).local()` or just `moment(date)`.  Both will leave you with that same moment in time, represented with the local time zone.

You may want to go back to your input and figure out how you got it to include `GMT+0100` when you are thinking it's actually a UTC value.  Consider that if you actually had 8:00 UTC, your input would say `09:00 GMT+0100`.

Comment: I'm using the following libraray http://jkbrzt.github.io/rrule/ - you can test what I mean by entering the following date `2016-10-27T08:00:00` into the dtstart field. It will generate the date as `20161027T060000Z` and in the results the library returns the dates as string in the following format `Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)`. I'm trying to format this string into local time. I can only manage to get it to work if i do `moment.utc(date, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss').local().format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");`. Doing `moment.(date).local()` doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you.  You should ask a new question specifically using this library, and create a jsFiddle showing how you are using this library and moment together.  All I can say is it sounds like you already have the local time, so it doesn't make since to me that you'd want to convert anything to get the local time.

Comment: Also, it would help to know what actual time zone you are located in, as it appears in one case you have GMT+2, and in another you have GMT+1.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use Moment TimeZone with MomentJS (http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
date = moment.tz("Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00", "GMT Standard Time");
date.clone().local().format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

**EDIT:**

Removing the `utc` part fixes it for me without Moment TimeZone:

```
date = 'Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)';
moment(date).local().format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: it doesnt work becuase my string is `"Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)"` where as you are using `"Thu Oct 27 2016 07:00:00", "GMT Standard Time"`

Comment: moment-timezone is not required for this, nor is `"GMT Standard Time"` a valid IANA time zone identifier.